# Moving ASP.NET web application to WPF

Tags: asp.net, wpf, web-applications

I am having a standard ASP.NET web application which I have been used for past one year. Now I need to move the web application to WPF.

What are the PRO's and CON's for moving my project to WPF?

What are the steps I need to do?

As far as I read, I can only use either Silverlight applications or XBAP applications for developing a WPF web application. Is that correct?

Kindly advice. Thanks in advance.